# How to make an option in the DropDown as first option only when list opens?

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0, asp.net-2.0

I have a DropDownList that is filled with values returned by a SQL Query. After the list is filled, I add two options manually to this DropDown: `-- Select --` and `ALL`.

When the page loads, the DropDownList shows `-- Select --` as the default value. When the user opens the DropDownList, the SQL Query returned list opens along with `ALL` option also.

I want to make this `ALL` appear as the fist item in the list when the list opens. I can't used: `DropDownList.SelectedIndex` because I want have already made `-- Select --` as the selected index.

How to make `ALL` the first option when the list opens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I understand your dream is to have a dropdownlist like this

```
SELECT(this one comes as selected)
ALL(the first item in the dropdownlist)    
V1(from your query)
V2(from your query)
V3(from your query)
..
.
```

---

You can do this

```
string selectStr = "SELECT";
string allStr = "ALL"

ListItem allLI = new ListItem(allStr,allStr);        
ListItem selectLI = new ListItem(selectStr,selectStr);

DropDownList.Items.Add(selectLI);
DropDownList.Items.Add(allLI);


//code to fill the DropDownList with the list that your query returns

DropDownList.SelectedValue = selectStr;
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess one solution would be to use a textbox / dropdownlist combined. And have the select text as default in the textbox. And the first option in dropdownlist would be ALL. Then disable the editing of the textbox to make it appear as a regular dropdownlist.

Like this: [Textbox and dropdownlist combined](http://www.michaelapproved.com/articles/textbox-and-dropdown-combined/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmmm. Good Alternative, but I can't add a TextBox. No permission to modify UI. That link is good. Is there any JQuery alternative?

Comment: Im not sure if you can alter the standard dropdownlist to fulfill your needs. Heres another link but i guess it also will need UI changes.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/combos.html

hope you find your answer.